# Как с помощью PendingIntent запустить стороннее приложение?

Tags: android, android-intent, pendingintent

Я не могу найти пример, который бы мне показал как с помощью PendingIntent запустить стороннее приложение. Везде используют явный интент, а с неявным интентом у меня не получается запустить приложение. Я не понимаю как правильно реализовать.

Моя попытка реализации:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0 , intent,0);
    try{
        pendingIntent.send();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: можно по названию пакета попробовать открывать

Comment: Я не знаю как по пакету открывать

Comment: Просто PendingIntent это же компонент, который позволяет другому приложению выполнять действия от вашего лица, так? А тогда как запустить это приложение которые выполнит вышенаписанное?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15465797/9363441 - вот например

Comment: Да это помогло, огромное спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно открывать по названию пакета.

Пример открытия браузера:

```
    Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.browser");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this,0,intent,0);
    try{
        pendingIntent.send();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```